# Storing String as a comma separated values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

Im iterating a NSDictionary as follows and assigning the values to a string if it contains a string  htttp.

```
for(id key in photos){

                     //NSLog(@"key=%@ value=%@", key, [photos objectForKey:key]);
    if ([[[photos objectForKey:key] stringByAppendingString: key] containsString:@"http"]){
    photoUrl = [[photos objectForKey:key] stringByAppendingString: key];
                     }
    NSLog(@"etf %@",photoUrl);

 }
```

1. How can I create a comma separated url  and assign it to photoUrl. For example, a nsdictionary might contains multiple urls so i want to concatenate all urls as a comma separated values and assign it to photoUrl later?
2. How can i retrieve those comma separated values later on?

Comment: Is photos the list of keys in the dictionary?

Comment: photos is NSDictionary? How are you iterating through a dictionary? U can iterate through the dictionary only when you have the array of keys of the dictionary

Comment: like this "a,b,c,d...."?

Comment: yes I wanna have it as a comma separated value and parse it later

Comment: Im iterating based on key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array in your loop,

```
NSArray *urls = [NSMutableArray array];
for (id key in photos) {
  NSString *photoUrl = [[photos[key] stringByAppendingString: key]
  if (photoUrl containsString:@"http"]){
    urls appendItem[photoUrl];
  }
}
```

Then you can create a CSV string with

```
NSString *csvUrls = [urls componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

and decompose it back with

```
NSArray *urls = [csvUrls componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting from some array

`NSString *joinedComponents = [array componentsJoinedByString:@","]`;

else you can iterate through some of your own collection

```
NSMutableString * string1 = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"this is my string"];

[string1 appendString:@" with more strings attached"];
```

Similarly you can get them separated later

```
NSArray *items = [string1 componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
```

Save the key value in the string and make your url.